# nHibernate: Reset an object's original state

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, session-state

I have a very basic query. I am using WPF Binding to edit a object which is loaded by a `ISession`. If somebody edits this object in the form, because of two way binding and a stateful session, whenever I close the session, changes to the object made in the form are stored back in the database. Which is the best way to avoid this?

The methods I know:

1. Shadow copy the object and use the copied object as the `DataContext` (the method I am using as of now).
2. `ISession.Clear`
3. Use `IStatelessSession`.

Is there any way to reset the object to it's original form before closing the `ISession`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look here: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/finding-dirty-properties-in-nhibernate.aspx

It is an example of finding dirty properties. NHibernate internally tracks a persistent object's state by way of the EntityEntry object.

This is useful for you, because with a little modification to the method above, you're able to get old values back ... which you can use to reset the properties.

As for closing your session causing the object to be flushed to the database, you can set the session FlushMode to FlushMode.Never. This will mean no database sync occurs until you call Session.Flush().

Alternatively, you can hook into IFlushEntityEventListener to reset the object state. There are a reasonable examples of using the NHibernate event system on google.

Comment: The example did it for me. Thanks. Although, the statement "This will mean no database sync occurs until you call `Session.Flush()`" is wrong. If I am using a transaction, a commit will sync the database, regardless of the setting of `FlushMode`.

Comment: I was assuming you weren't using a transaction. What would be the point of that if you're not going to update the data?

Comment: I am not saying that I am using one, I am just clarifying that there is an exception possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

See [Managing the caches](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-sessioncache) on [NHibernate Forge](http://nhforge.org/):

> When Flush() is subsequently called, the state of that object will be synchronized with the database. If you do not want this synchronization to occur or if you are processing a huge number of objects and need to manage memory efficiently, the Evict() method may be used to remove the object and its collections from the first-level cache.

I think that sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of transactions. You just rollbackthe transaction if that is the case? what do you think?

Comment: a) That's an unnecessary transaction which could potentially lock the row, depending on the isolation level.

Comment: b) doesn't help reset the object.

Comment: wow! am i hearing this correctly "Transactions are unnecessary"

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I meant opening transactions for the sole purpose of rolling them back is not necessary ... especially when there are other trivial means.

Comment: fyi that is what an implicit transaction is.

Comment: @zzzz let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2388/discussion-between-thilak-nathen-and-zzzz)